# HTML 5 Canvas - width of the line when drawing

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, candlestick-chart

I am working with canvas and java script and have issue with the width of the line for candlesticks (stock market analysis).

I call function which draws rectangle like this:

```
DrawRectangle(context0, x , y, w , h, '#fff','#000', false);
```

Here is this function to draw rectangle:

```
function DrawRectangle(context0, x, y, w, h, color, border, fill) {     
  context0.fillStyle = color;
  context0.beginPath();
  context0.rect(x, y, w, h);
  context0.closePath();
  context0.lineWidth = 1;
  context0.strokeStyle = border;
  context0.stroke();
  if (fill) context0.fill();
}
```

By the last parameter I define if this rectangle should be filled or not.
I would like to use the WHITE color which will fill rectangle. Here is how I will do it:

```
DrawRectangle(context0, x , y, w , h, '#fff','#000', true);
```

The problem is the once I use it the width of the line is not same as other lines.

here is first result (when I use TRUE to fill rectangle):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uckGL.png)

and this is second (when I use FALSE)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U4VfJ.png)

In the first case line width is not the same and I am looking for proper solution.

Without going much into details, the candlestick has upper and bottom shadows (lines).
I draw the using following function:

```
function DrawLine(context0, startx, starty, endx, endy, color) {
  context0.beginPath();
  context0.moveTo(startx, starty);
  context0.lineTo(endx, endy);
  context0.closePath();
  context0.lineWidth = 1;
  context0.strokeStyle = color;
  context0.stroke();
}
```

In the function which draws candlesticks I call this function like this:

```
DrawLine(context0, x1 , y1 , x2 , y2 ,'#000');
```

As you can see in both cases `context0.lineWidth = 1` but this does not give the same results.
I can use a trick and do it by calling function twice. Like this:

```
DrawRectangle(context0, x , y, w , h, '#fff','#000', true);
DrawRectangle(context0, x , y, w , h, '#fff','#000', false);
```

But I do not like this solution (performance).

Any other ideas?

Comment: what if you do .stroke() after your fill logic? Fill first, and then draw the border. Not 100% sure without testing, but should be quick to test on your end.

Comment: The drawn stroke line extends from the edges, both inwards and outwards. A line width of 1 creates a semitransparent line with a width of 2 pixels, with the outer half being visible around the fill area, the inner half of it covered by it. To fix this, you need `context0.rect(x + 0.5, y + 0.5, w - 1, h - 1);` and `stroke()` after `fill()`

Comment: stroke() after fill() solved the issue. now I do not need to execute DrawRectange twice. the trick explained by @Chris G makes the rectangle lines smaller, but how do I do the same for DrawLine() function in case I want to have 1px?

Comment: Just use `.5` coordinates; the reasoning is that the line will extend `0.5` pixels in both directions, thus covering exactly one pixel.